# roslaunch for multi-robot team

Tags: ros, roslaunch, namespace, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all:

I want to write a roslaunch file to launch the same set of nodes, identically configured, on a number of robots.  What's the most economical way to write a launch file or files to do that?  The requirements are:

- There are about 20 parameters to configure each node.  I want to set the parameters in only one place, so I don't want these to be renamed/remapped.
- Each robot runs six nodes that publish four topics and provide one service.  These were not written with multiple robots in mind, so they must each be renamed, e.g. from "/cmd_vel" to "/machine1/cmd_vel."

In this case "economical" means not only short, but requiring the least work to add and subtract robots from the ensemble.  I thought of writing a launch file for a single robot and then including it multiple times in a master file:

Wouldn't that change the parameter names along with the topic and service names?  It also seems a little clunky.  Is there a better way?

Bonus question: I wish I knew an easy way to supply each robot with a list of all the others in the launch file, or even just a list of all the robots on the team.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11847/roslaunch-for-multi-robot-team/) by [Tom Sgouros](https://answers.ros.org/users/1205/tom-sgouros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines), [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup), and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects). The third link is probably the most relevant. Take a look at section 1.3. These pages talk about running ROS across multiple machines. The nodes to run on any machine will be configured with the `<machine>` tag.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Max Pfingsthorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4191/max-pfingsthorn/) on 2013-07-24**:
Just a word of caution: Don't do this over an unreliable (e.g. wireless) connection. Check http://ros.org/wiki/rocon_multimaster for something to do actual distributed ROS.